# Typescript: express optional parameter in generic

Tags: typescript, generics, undefined, option-type

Apparently in typescript there's a difference between optional parameter and parameter of union type with undefined

```
function test(s: string|undefined) {}

function test2(s?: string) {}

test() // error: An argument for 's' was not provided
test2() // OK
```

I want to declare a generic function that depending on the provided type would have its parameter optional or required. For example:

```
// Intention: if type is the same as its Partial counterpart then the parameter can be made optional
type MaybeOptional<T> = Partial<T> extends T ? T|undefined : T

type O = {
  name?: string
}

function generic<T extends any>(t: MaybeOptional<T>) {}

generic<O>({name:""})
generic<O>() // error. An argument for 't' was not provided.
```

How can I express such intention in Typescript? Can I assign this 'optional' trait through generics?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to talk about a function's argument list in a more flexible way:

```
function generic<T extends any>(...args: Partial<T> extends T ? [t?: T] : [t: T]) { }
```

If, when you call `generic<T>()`, the type `T` is all-optional and `Partial<T> extends T`, this reduces to `(...args: [t?: T]) => void`, meaning "a list of arguments whose length is one and whose one element is optional and of type `T`", which reduces to `(t?: T) => void)`.  If, on the other hand, the type `T` is not all-optional, then this reduces to `(...args: [t: T])=>void`; the same as before except the element is required, which reduces to `(t: T) => void`.

Let's test it:

```
type O = {
  name?: string
}
generic<O>({ name: "" }); // okay
generic<O>({}); // okay
generic<O>(); // okay

type R = {
  name: string;
}
generic<R>({ name: "" }); // okay
generic<R>({}); // error
generic<R>(); // error
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJxhAPAFUVQA8p0ATAZ0QEMwBPAPgAoA6dmzZSgLkQAVOsGgBsCjIqQrVCAfkQBtKLL74Auoj5LVagJSIA3ogC+AWABQFqPQAOqRAHlEAXkMXEiMDQC2qFYkoobDBkCzNzNAxsPAcWIy9fPgAiJJNdAG5EAHosxDgAaxp6C0isHFxY5gNjDOzcgqKS9DKYllqcvMLiy3NrO0QAJRc3cw8E1D5A4OR0sKao8oG4zx8JxBS0zI6G7tLo3CWqmq3crEw4THmWg7aTokxzzCA)